# How to ask donors to send bitcoin if they are not bitcoin enthusiasts?

Tags: transactions, donation

Have idea for wonderful service many would want to donate to see happen. Those who donate though know nothing of bitcoin. Google reveals much trouble with bitcoin<->paypal or bitcoin<->creditcard gateways.

Exists any credible and reliable service that does this?

Bitcoiners too small group to expect enough from them, bitcoin system too difficult for non-bitcoiners to donate. Non bitcoin donations undermine concept.

Answer (score 1):

CoinBase says that they hope to offer a method to purchase bitcoins using credit card.

In the meantime, that's not happening or at least not without going through some method like VirWoX (buy SLLs there and trade those SLLs for BTCs).

There are cash deposit methods.  Depositing cash at a bank or 7-11, Walmart, CVS is going to be the fastest and easiest way.

- http://www.BitInstant.com (Deposit at major banks, 7-11, Walmart, CVS, Moneygram, etc., or in Brazil using Boleto or Banco Recomendito, or in Russia, using Qiwi or Cyberplat.)
- http://www.CAVirtEx.com (Deposit cash at several banks)
- http://www.Spendbitcoins.com (Deposit cash at a bank in Australia)
- http://www.MrBitcoins.com (Deposit at a bank in U.S., India, Australia)
- http://BitcoinNordic.com (Purchase CashU or UKash in dozens of countries)
- http://www.MtGox.com (Deposit cash at any Barclay's in the UK)

There are also individual traders in 70 countries and hundreds of cities:

- http://www.localbitcoins.com

Comment: It is, how you say, ridiculos to expect donors to go to so many trouble when only ask of them 1 euro or less. Yet unlikely to expect those already involved to be interested.